# Using a panel as filter

Tags: c#, winforms

As an initial note, I don't expect the code for this part of my software, but what I need, and would appreciate, it is a starting point and some ideas.

I have a panel like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B98UpTa2n4XbZUFuclhDbG9pV1k/view?usp=sharing

I need to use this panel as a date filter (connected with a Data Base). So, in one edge I will have a starting date and the other an ending date. The user must be able to interact with this panel to select the "gap" of dates that he/she would like to apply as a filter to a plotting graph.

Again, I don't expect the code for this part of my tool. I am just kind of lost in how should I start coding, also, I did not find anything specific about this online.

Thank you,

Comment: So where are the date time entered in the panel?

Comment: Your "panel" is that a control you made? Is that something you found on the Internet? Does this "panel" have events that fire upon changing the bars? So basically, my question what is it that you already have?

Comment: @Abhishek, this is one of my questions. Should I create 2 labels with the date time that the panel will populate?

Comment: @Abhishek dont think you are supposed to enter anything. It should be a two way slider where the left edge is a min date and the right edge is the max date, and with the two sliders you can specify a range.

Comment: @RandRandom , my "panel" was created by me. I am not sure if they have the same or similar online. This panel, so far, it is a "sliding panel" that you can click, hold, and drag to increase or decrease the gap of dates/time that I would like to plot.

In other words, the user can choose a big gap of dates or shrink the panel and choose only a few days.

Comment: @FabioSoares you should give a google search a try for "slider" thats the kind of control you want. I would start from there, doing your own slider control is possible but I doubt you have the knowledge to do so, sorry,

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: @TaW his image is saying all :)

Comment: It is, but only __after__ looking at it! The purpose of Tags is to let us filter questions we are or are niot interested in. The image is useless for this!

Comment: Winforms been a while. So no idea if it works, how about this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983717(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DateTimePicker control on both sides of the panel (dtpFrom and dtpTo) then use the values to add to a query executed against the database.

On the ValueChange events for both the dtpFrom and toDate, you could validate that the fromDate is less than the toDate and vice versa, then call a function that executes the query and returns the results, or just filters results already in an existing dataset.

Comment: Not th same feeling imo.